# Reply with a picture in telegram via pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to reply messages with photo in telegram via pytelegrambotapi
I saw the official documentation of pytelegram bot api but got nothing
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
bot.send_photo(chatid, photo, reply_to_message_id=msgidwhichuwanttoreply)
```

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=send_photo#telegram.Bot.send_photo